# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onUpdateUser

Tags: reactjs

I am getting Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onUpdateUser is not a function
error.I have done binding also in constructor.But why it keep throwing same error when i strats writing anything in textbox.

```
 class App extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onUpdateUser = this.onUpdateUser.bind(this);
      }


    onUpdateUser(event){
      this.props.onUpdateUser(event.target.value);
    }

      render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <p>
                Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
              </p>

              <input onChange={this.onUpdateUser}/>
              {this.props.user}
            </header>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: If the error is about `this.props.onUpdateUser`, then there is a problem with your `props`. Did you pass down the function properly from the parent component? `console.log(this.props.onUpdateUser)` should give back a `function` declaration.

Comment: share the code from the parent component, and it is likely that onUpdateUser is not passed as a prop